# Rearragne / group PHP array items based on common values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working with a library system that outputs a PHP array organized by checkout id, e.g.:

```
Array (
    [6912] => Array (
        [name] => John Doe
        [email] => johndoe@email.com
        [telephone] => 55555555
        [book] => Gone With the Wind
        [book_id] => 410
    )
    [6913] => Array (
        [name] => John Doe
        [email] => johndoe@email.com
        [telephone] => 55555555
        [book] => War and Peace
        [book_id] => 107
    )
    [6914] => Array (
        [name] => John Doe
        [email] => johndoe@email.com
        [telephone] => 55555555
        [book] => Pride and Prejudice
        [book_id] => 222
    )
)
```

What is the most efficient way to consolidate the common values and rearrange this array to something like this:

```
Array (
    [name] => John Doe
    [email] => johndoe@email.com
    [telephone] => 55555555
    [checked_out] => Array (
        [6912] => Array (
            [book] => Gone With the Wind
            [book_id] => 410
        )
        [6913] => Array (
            [book] => War and Peace
            [book_id] => 107
        )
        [6914] => Array (
            [book] => Pride and Prejudice
            [book_id] => 222
        )
    )
)
```

**CLARIFICATION**

This array is what I get back if i query by the user_id for "John Doe", so you can assume that the name, email, and telephone fields will always be the same in this example.

So far I have two different solutions to do this, but at the moment I'm not sure which is more efficient, or even if it makes a measurable difference. Even if I increase the checkout time frame to one year, I don't expect the array to contain more than 182 items (assuming they check out a book and return it the next day). I will play with both solutions and pick one that is more intuitive to me.  Thanks so much, guys!

Comment: The shown output is invalid to construct from the input if under the assumption that not all items have the same "common values". Imagine when there are two distinct telephone numbers. That is, the output should be `array(telephone1 => array(name => .., checked_out => array(..)), telephone2 => ..)` or similar, where each top-level key (or array item) represents a different "common values" group. It is also important to be explicit about which "common values" define a group (ie. what happens if two people share a phone number?)

Comment: so this final output array can only have one person in the end?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. To clarify, this is an output for the user John Doe only, so we can assume that all name, email, and telephone values will stay constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This eliminates the if check on each item in the foreach loop. This also assumes you have only unique email, name and telephone in all the items.

[Demo Here](http://codepad.org/9Neb9Bu3)

```
$checked_out = array(
    6912=>array('name'=>'John Doe', 'email'=> 'johndoe@email.com', 'telephone'=>'55555555', 'book'=>'Gone With the Wind', 'book_id' =>410),
    6913=>array('name'=>'John Doe', 'email'=> 'johndoe@email.com', 'telephone'=>'55555555', 'book'=>'War and Peace', 'book_id' =>107),
    6914=>array('name'=>'John Doe', 'email'=> 'johndoe@email.com', 'telephone'=>'55555555', 'book'=>'Pride and Prejudice', 'book_id' =>222)
    );
$output = array();
$first_value = reset($checked_out);
$output['name']=$first_value['name'];
$output['email']=$first_value['email'];
$output['telephone']=$first_value['telephone'];
foreach ($checked_out as $key=>$value){
    $output['checked_out'][$key] = array('book'=>$value['book'],'book_id'=>$value['book_id']);
}

print_r($output);
```

Note: don't know this is the fastest way. But this is the fastest I can think of right now.

Comment: This will work *iff* there is only one "common values" group; I'm not sure if this is the case or the OP simply underspecified the task.

Comment: @user2864740 exactly that is why i added the assumption, and there is no place for additional users in the output.

Comment: Thanks, this is clever. I'm all for not having conditional checks in loops if at all possible :).

Comment: Hi @bansi... am having almost a similar problem as in this question, but my problem is, i have multiple values repeated, like suppose for countries and states.. for Country "India", i have some 20 states and for USA i have "25" states... how can i change this code, to accomplish that.. can you please give me a suggestion... Thank You..

Answer (score 1):

Just create it on a new one, push the name, email, tel # once, then push the checkout items. Example: [Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RQynUk)

```
$checked_out = array();
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    // just a simple initial insertion
    if(empty($checked_out)) {
        $checked_out = array(
            'name' => $value['name'],
            'email' => $value['email'],
            'telephone' => $value['telephone'],
        );
    }
    // push checked out items
    $checked_out['checked_out'][$key] = array('book' => $value['book'], 'book_id' => $value['book_id']);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($checked_out);
```

Note: I do not know if using array functions for this one will be faster.

Comment: "will be faster" --- and it actually doesn't matter for 3 elements array.

Comment: isn't it better to use `reset` to populate `name`, `email` etc instead of an `if` for each item in the array?

Comment: This will work *iff* there is only one "common values" group; I'm not sure if this is the case or the OP simply underspecified the task.

Comment: @user2864740 actually i asked the OP for clarification, i asked whether in the end, there is only one user that will checkout, if there are multiple, then the case would be different

Comment: Hi @Ghost ... am having almost a similar problem as in this question, but my problem is, i have multiple values repeated, like suppose for countries and states.. for Country "India", i have some 20 states and for USA i have "25" states... how can i change this code, to accomplish that.. can you please give me a suggestion... Thank You..

Comment: @phpfresher the same concept applies, you'll just need to group them also, but in order to accomodate the same values, just push them in the same key then, create another dimension, without looking at the codes, you could probably use some thing like this: `$checked_out['checked_out'][$key][] = the array or value`, mind the additional `[]` on the assignment

Comment: Hi @Ghost... i have tried this too... but it's not working fine.. i've pasted the array and the output i got with your code in this link. http://codepad.org/dd1fzJ1c .... Here "Not Mentioned" is one countryname and "India" is one country name.. i want to get both of them separately.. but all are coming in "Not Mentioned"... I hope you understood what am saying.. Can you please check it once and give me a suggestion.. Thank You.

Comment: @phpfresher i'm a little bit busy right now but here's a start, use the country name as your key to gather those: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zAE2Jf  pastebin link http://pastebin.com/9fatnDwg

Comment: Hi @Ghost... Sorry for the late reply and thanks for the links.. I already used the country name in the key.. But i want "ID" also... I cannot store both in the same key know.. that's why am trying like this.. Any how thanks for your help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code :

```
$data = array();
$data['name'] = 'John Doe';
$data['email'] = 'johndoe@email.com';
$data['telephone'] = 5555555555;
$data['checkout'] = array(
6912 => array(
    'book' => 'Gone With the Wind',
    'book_id' => 410
),
6913 => array(
    'book' => 'War and Peace',
    'book_id' => 107
),
6914 => array(
    'book' => 'Pride and Prejudice',
    'book_id' => 222
)
);
```